# Centos7: passwordless SSH over ldap

Tags: linux, ssh, root

in my company we have all servers Centos6/RedHat6, but now I was tasked to update it to Centos 7.
I have created one C7 virtual machine and I have problem with passwordless access.
It is als oworth to mention that we use ldap for users managment with shared home folders for each user. I was thinking maybe homes aren't mounted? But home for user groupmaster is permanently mounted

Im getting:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
myuser@10.42.112.32's password:
```

My SSHd config:

```
[root@germanium ~]# grep -v '#' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Protocol 2

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes

PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

AllowUsers root myuser groupmaster
```

Furthermore: my root passwordless access works.

UPDATE:
WHen I've started sshd with debug mode I could connect WITHOUT password. I've used command:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

Whats the difference between this and

```
systemctl start sshd
```

?

Comment: have you change pam_winbind.conf  in /etc/security ? as well as samba.conf ?

Comment: what should I do there? I think I did not

Comment: Other servers (centos6 ones) does not have modifies pan_winbind nor samba... Other ideas?

Comment: Did you connect to AD ? I mean joinning AD using a computer account ?

Comment: Running sshd manually with `-d` (debug mode) option will help to understand where the problem is. And please be aware that manually started sshd will exit after each connection attempt therefore you need re-start it after once "debugging" trial.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited vim /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service so it starts sshd with triple debug mode and saving log to /tmp:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D -ddd -E /log/sshd.log $OPTIONS
```

There I've discovered that SSHD cannot read users .ssh files.
Further investigation I've found it's due to SELinux. Unfortunatelly I had no idea how to fix it, so I set SELinux into permissive mode.
Finally it worked!